# Verifying that a string does not contain curly brackets other than those used for formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am trying to build a function which verifies that a string does not contain curly brackets (`{` and `}`), other than those which may be used for one-level formatting. That is, I wish to allow curly brackets which may vanish after a single call to the `.format` method of the string.

For example, if this verification function is called `no_curly_braces`, the following results should be returned:

```
>>> no_curly_brackets("word")
True
>>> no_curly_brackets("{word")  # False, as .format raises ValueError
False
>>> no_curly_brackets("{}word")  # True, as .format(3) returns '3word'
True
>>> no_curly_brackets("{word}")  # True, as .format(word=3) returns '3'
True
>>> no_curly_brackets("{{word}}")  # False, as .format returns '{word}'
False
>>> no_curly_brackets("{{{word}}}")  # False, as .format(word='a') returns '{a}'
False
>>> no_curly_brackets("{word}{{}}")  # False, as .format(word=3) returns '3{}'
False
```

and so on.

My problem is that attempts like `"{" in str` will fail (as templates may hold these curly brackets), and I cannot wish to format without knowing what I should provide to the `.format` method, in order to try to make the relevant curly brackets vanish.

Comment: XY problem? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The issue is this: no matter how you'll format `{{word}}` or `{{{word}}}`, you'll stay with curly brackets after a single call to `.format`.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: this is asked (mainly) for pure curiosity.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to check for 1) unbalanced braces, and 2) nested braces. So scan your string and for each `{` increment a counter and for each `}`, decrement it. If the count is ever anything except 0 or 1, or if the count is not zero at the end, then complain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`string.Formatter()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter):

```
from string import Formatter

def no_curly_brackets(fmt):
    try:
        parsed = Formatter().parse(fmt)
        return not any('{' in lt or '}' in lt for lt, _, _, _ in parsed)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Basically anything that's parsable as a format and doesn't contain a curly brace in the parsed literal text would be `True`.

This matches all your test cases:

```
>>> for test in tests:
...     print test, no_curly_brackets(test)
... 
word True
{word False
{}word True
{word} True
{{word}} False
{{{word}}} False
{word}{{}} False
```

plus a few of my own:

```
>>> no_curly_brackets('word}}')
False
>>> no_curly_brackets('{{word')
False
>>> no_curly_brackets('word{{}}')
False
```

Comment: I'm working on a similar approach, but I think it'll have to be a little more clever.  Consider the `"{{word}}"` case.  [Kind of funny: the only difference between our codes was that I kept the OP's "word" as the argument name and that I put the `return True` in the `try`.  Otherwise identical..]

Comment: @DSM: Indeed; adjusted to allow for the more stringent restrictions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: your speed is overwhelming.

Comment: The last case should be False, shouldn't it?  (Going to make you work for it, despite what day it is. :-)

Comment: @DSM: No worries, I purchased the 'guaranteed to find the right answer' feature with my mined Unicoins!

Comment: Your code fails on this particular test_case **'{1.}'** (when the identifier is not a valid python var name), not sure if it's a concern for the OP though.

Comment: @SamyArous: That's at best a bug in the Python `str.format()` implementation; that syntax actually results in a `ValueError: Empty attribute in format string` exception only after parsing.

Comment: @SamyArous: You could add support for that by using `any('{' in lt or '}' in lt or fn is None or list(fn._formatter_field_name_split()[1]) is None for lt, fn, _, _ in parsed)`

Comment: @SamyArous: that'll throw the same exception, putting us in the `ValueError` exception handler. But that's still not a formatting string with literal curly braces either.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer based on my comment above:

```
def no_curly_brackets(fmt):
  n = 0
  for c in fmt:
    if c == '{':
      n=n+1
    elif c == '}':
      n=n-1
    if n < 0 or n > 1:
      return False
  return (n == 0)
```

Some sample results:

```
word True
{word False
{}word True
{word} True
{{word}} False
{{{word}}} False
{word}{{}} False
```